# (multiple) double quote and variable

Tags: bash

putting multiple double quote to a bash variable seems have the same result to putting one or no double quote.

e.g., `t1=a`, `t2="a"`, `t3=""a""`, echo them prints the same result: `a`. Are there any difference?

Finally, what the difference between `if [ $x == "valid" ]; then`, `if [ ""$x"" == "valid" ]; then` and `if [ "$x" == "valid" ]; then`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consecutive quotes are simply *superfluous*.

This doesn't imply that an unquoted variable behaves similarly to a quoted one.

The following example should clarify it:

```
$ set -x                       # enable xtrace
$ foo=""
+ foo=
$ [ -n $foo ] && echo y        # unquoted variable results in incorrect result for "string not empty" check
+ '[' -n ']'
+ echo y
y
$ [ -n "$foo" ] && echo y      # quoted variable results in correct result for the same check
+ '[' -n '' ']'
$ [ -n ""$foo"" ] && echo y
+ '[' -n '' ']'
$ echo "hey"
+ echo hey
hey
$ echo ""hey""                 # produces same result as in the previous case
+ echo hey
hey
$ echo """hey"""
+ echo hey
hey
```

Comment: can you explain or provide reference for why `unquoted variable results in incorrect result for "string not empty" check`, I am a beginner, it's not clear to me.

Comment: @HelinWang That is precisely why I had turned the trace on.  The lines beginning with a `+` show how the shell interprets the command.  Please see that and let me know should you have any doubts.

Comment: "Consecutive quotes are simply superfluous" would seem to imply that any number of consecutive quotes are identical to a single character. Actually, each pair of consecutive quotes just defines an empty string. Consider something like `echo """hey     there"""` vs. `echo ""hey     there""`.

Answer (score 1):

A quote in bash is like a switch. When bash sees a quote, it switches quoting on. When it sees another quote, it switches it OFF.

Hence `echo ""a""` is same as `echo a`

If x is empty or unset, then you will have to provide quotes around the variable, otherwise bash will give an error.

Quoting is very important when you are dealing with files. $ is just a substitution command and if your filename has a space, then $ simply expands the filename. If you do not have quotes around it then bash will treat it like two words instead of one.

Check this tutorial. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html

Comment: what is difference between quote switched ON and OFF? I am getting `echo "a"` (ON) same as `echo a` (OFF).

Comment: thanks for the response, now I could understand. I have choose devnull's answer for simplicity and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Double double quotes is an empty double quote.  It is not strictly meaningless because it can count as an argument, for instance: `echo a b` is different from `echo a "" b`.  The empty double quotes is treated as an argument and so two spaces are printed out between a an b.

`echo ""a` and `t3=""a""` are pointless uses of empty double quotes.  The empty string is included as part of the a, so it has no effect.

The proper way to do a variable check is this: `if [ "$x" = "some text" ]; then ...`
If x is empty, it will be treated as an empty argument (which is the desired behavior.)

If you skip the quotes: `if [ $x = "this is bad" ]; then ...` you will have a problem if x is empty, or if it contains spaces. The test would not even see the x at all, and = would be the first argument.

Using double double quotes around the x: `if [ ""$x"" = "this is bad" ]; then ...` would actually still work properly if x is empty.  It would have a problem, however, if x contained spaces.  e.g. `x="a b"`.  The test would see a and b as separate arguments, which does not make sense.

If you want to include a literal double quote character in an argument, use a backslash: `echo "\""` or just `echo \"`.

Ultimately the whole point of double quotes is manipulating how the command line is split into arguments.  `echo "a"`, `echo a` and `echo ""a""` all have a single 'a' character as their first argument, and are therefore exactly equivalent.  `echo a  b` and `echo "a  b"` are not equivalent. The first has two arguments and the second only has one.  In the first case, the double space will be collapsed to a single space separating the arguments.  The double space will be preserved as part of the argument in the second case.